# share to social iphone native code

Tags: iphone, cordova, share

I want to share messages to social networks from my phonegap application. For that i m creating plugin for iphone and android.

i found code for android:

```
String message = "Text I wan't to share."
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("text/plain");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Title of the dialog the system will open"));
```

But i can't able to find code for iphone.. can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FacebookConnect](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/FacebookConnect) plugin authorise by Phonegap team.

- This plugin provides a simple way to use Facebook Graph API in
  Cordova.
- This plugin is built for Cordova >= v2.1.0 with ARC. Both iOS &
  Android are supported with the same javascript interface.

Use can also use Dave johnson's [plugin](https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect), this also support iOS and Android platform.

Comment: Thank you Mayur.. but this is only for facebook.. i want to share message to all social networks. i don't want to create separate plugin for each..  i am trying to get plugin to share msg to all social networks...

Answer (score 0):

The share `Intent` is part of the Android SDK and not iOS! Nothing like this exists for iOS and you will just have to integrate each social network separately.

You may want to look at [this](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/09/25/facebook-sdk-for-ios-and-the-ios-6-facebook-integration/) and [this](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios) for facebook and twitter integration as these are now part of iOS (Twitter was integrated into iOS 5, Facebook in iOS 6).